# Regex to match and move HTML

Tags: html, regex

I need to replace an html snippet present in numerous files, capturing all the information that's between the `<td>` tags and replacing it with the (wrong) information that's inside the `<li>` tags.

The code looks like this:

```
<li><b>Details:</b> WRONG TEXT</li>
<li><b>Product:</b> WRONG TEXT</li>
<li><b>Requirements:</b> WRONG TEXT</li>

// There are a lot of codes that should not be changed here, between the above and the one below.

<td>CORRECT TEXT</td>
<td>CORRECT TEXT</td>
<td>CORRECT TEXT</td>
```

It should look like this:

```
<li><b>Details:</b> CORRECT TEXT</li>
<li><b>Product:</b> CORRECT TEXT</li>
<li><b>Requirements:</b> CORRECT TEXT</li>
```

I created this regex below. .

```
(?s)(<li><b>.*?:<\/b>\s+(.*)<\/li>).*?<td>(.*)<\/td>
```

But it replaces each other, not just the text between the tags.

Could someone give me a hint, please?

**EDIT**

Added necessary information in the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, with an expression similar to,

```
(<li><b>.*?<\/b>).*?<\/li>\s*(<li><b>.*?<\/b>).*?<\/li>\s*(<li><b>.*?<\/b>).*?<\/li>(\s*.*?)<td>(.*?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.*?)<\/td>\s*<td>(.*?)<\/td>
```

and some replacement such as,

```
$1 $5</li>\n$2 $6</li>\n$3 $7</li>\n$4
```

we'd be able to do that, assuming that there would be three instances.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPgLVF/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Emma. I tried your code and it seems didn't work :(  When i run it the ST3 returns the message "No matches found". I tried some other code on the regex101 site, but it didn't work either. Anyway, thanks for your interest in helping.

Comment: Hi Emma, Thanks for the feedback. My mistake. The code really works. But, by my mistake, I posted only the lines of code I want to change. In fact, among the lines that will be changed by regex there are a lot of other codes. I edited the topic post by add the correct information. In case, when I remove the codes that are between the passages I want to change, the regex works perfectly. How could I make regex "ignore" (without changes) the codes that are between the sections that should be changed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Emma, it worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your patience and assistance. Saved my day. Cheers from Greece =)